# Position of line relative to a concave polygon

Tags: algorithms, polygons

How can I determine mathematically and graphically the position of a line relative to a concave polygon? (e.g. outside, inside, on edge, intersect)

For a convex polygon, I think I could use Cyrus-Beck, but not for concave.

Comment: I think that if you take the convex hull and use your convex algorithm on that, you should get the correct result (assuming lines are all infinitely long), but I don't have a good proof at the moment. You could also split it up into convex polygons then use the convex algorithm

Comment: can you decompose the polygon into (few) convex parts ?

Comment: @GCab Yes, I could use triangulation

Comment: With a non-convex polygon you can get multiple answers such as *on edge* and *intersect*